# PreparedStatement: Query, or Update?

Tags: java, jdbc

Given an instance stmt of java.sql.PreparedStatement, I can either do `stmt.executeQuery()`, if my SQL statement is a SELECT, that returns a result, or I can do `stmt.executeUpdate()` for an INSERT, or UPDATE.

Now, suggest the case, where I don't know, what kind of SQL statement is being executed? I was hoping for something convenient, like `stmt.hasResultSet()`, but that doesn't exist. Parsing the SQL statement doesn't seem a good option.

Comment: There's also a method [`execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()), which returns *`true` if the first result is a `ResultSet` object; `false` if the first result is an update count or there is no result*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do always an `executeQuery()` but passing to a resultset, like:

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

After you have your ResultSet, you can then get its metadata:

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
```

In this metadata you can check the getColumnCount() for if it is zero or more, with this you can even get the precise number of columns returned to perform a generic parse with a loop:

```
final ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
final int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

if (columnCount > 0) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= columnCount ; i++) {
            sb.append(rs.getString(i));
            if (i < columnCount) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
        }
        
        temp.add(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: This will fail with an exception if the statement does not produce a result set.

Comment: Of course, it will fail if there's no result set, or if the connection is not made, or whatever else happens, the point is to show how to fix the immediate issue asked here, I'm not providing a whole project, just the information that the possibility exists and how to do it, other treatments around it for sure a necessary, just like most answers here, no one posts a complete and working Class, just enough code to cover the answer and explanations

Comment: The OP is explicitly asking what to do when they do not know what type of SQL statement is going to be executed. Your answer is to use `executeQuery()`, while that is not suitable for that purpose. JDBC explicitly defines `execute()` for cases where you don't know what type of statement is going to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

The JDBC API provides the [`PreparedStatement.execute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute()) method (and [`Statement.execute(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String))) exactly for this purpose:

> Executes the SQL statement in this `PreparedStatement` object, which
> may be any kind of SQL statement. Some prepared statements return
> multiple results; the `execute` method handles these complex
> statements as well as the simpler form of statements handled by the
> methods `executeQuery` and `executeUpdate`.
>
> The `execute` method returns a `boolean` to indicate the form of the
> first result. You must call either the method `getResultSet` or
> `getUpdateCount` to retrieve the result; you must call
> `getMoreResults` to move to any subsequent result(s).
>
> **Returns:**
>  `true` if the first result is a `ResultSet` object; `false` if
> the first result is an update count or there is no result

So, to execute an unknown statement, you need to do something like:

```java
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(unknownStatement)) {
    // set variables ...

    boolean currentResult = pstmt.execute();
    while (true) {
        if (currentResult) {
            try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.getResultSet()) {
                // process result set
            }
        } else {
            int updateCount = pstmt.getUpdateCount();
            if (updateCount == -1) {
                // no more results
                break;
            }
            // do something with update count
        }
        currentResult = pstmt.getMoreResults();
    }
}
```

The loop is there because some database systems (e.g. SQL Server), can produce multiple result sets and multiple update counts, and this will handle all of them.